# How to add Header row for multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: pandas

I am looking for `"Reagion"` on top of `"obv"` .

```
     obv   East     West    North   South
0   Males   50      142     131      70
1   Females 435     1523    1356    750
```

Expected Output is:-

```
    Region  East    West    North   South
    obv
   Males    50      142     131      70
  Females   435     1523    1356    750
```

Comment: Try `rename_axis`, if not working please add expected output to question.

Comment: Thanks but rename_axis didn't work. Please help.

Comment: What is `print (df.columns)` ? `print (df.index.name)` ?

Comment: print (br1.columns)
print (br1.index.name)

Index(['obv', 'East', 'West', 'North', 'South'], dtype='object')
value

Comment: Super, how working `df = df.set_index('obv').rename_axis('Region', axis=1)` ?

Comment: Super, glad can help! ;)